# Allocating a 2D contiguous array within a function

Tags: c

I am trying to allocate a 2d contiguous array using C99 variable length arrays. Something like this:

```
size_t rows = 5, cols = 5;
double (*array)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof *array);
```

The trouble is, I want to do the allocation in a function. I'm guessing that in order to do so, I need to declare the array first and then pass its address to the function. I've been trying things like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void allocate(double *((*grid)[]), size_t cols)
{
    size_t rows = 5; // in practice this the result of a computation
    double (*array)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof *array);
    *grid = array;
}


int main ()
{
    size_t cols = 5;
    double (*grid)[cols];    // note: edited to fix typo (was [])
    allocate(&grid, cols);

    return 0;
}
```

My compiler (GCC 4.7.1) is giving me the following warnings/errors:

```
$ gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 2d.c -o 2d
2d.c: In function ‘allocate’:
2d.c:8:5: error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
2d.c: In function ‘main’:
2d.c:16:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘allocate’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
2d.c:4:6: note: expected ‘double * (*)[]’ but argument is of type ‘double (**)[]’
```

I have tried many variations of this kind of thing but I am clearly missing something. I would like to have a contiguous 2d array accessible like `grid[j][i]` from `main` but perform the allocation in a separate function. How can I do this?

Comment: should be `void allocate(double (**grid)[], size_t cols)`

Comment: Try allocating for all rows first. Dereferencing to some index gives you column address. Allocate for all columns then.

Comment: Seems to me that returning the address of the first row (instead of having an "out parameter")  would be easier, easier to write and easier to understand: In allocate simply `return array; `, and in main simply `grid = allocate(...);`. Ah: The return type would best be done with a typedef (@user3477950).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void allocate( size_t cols, double (**arr)[cols] )
{
  size_t rows = ...;
  *arr = malloc( sizeof **arr * rows );
}
```

**Edit**

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t get_rows( void )
{
  return 5;
}

void allocate( size_t cols, double (**arr)[cols] )
{
  size_t rows = get_rows();
  *arr = malloc( sizeof **arr * rows );
  if ( *arr )
  {
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++ )
      for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++ )
        (*arr)[r][c] = r * cols + c;
  }
}

int main( void )
{
  size_t cols = 5;
  double (*arr)[cols] = NULL;
  allocate( cols, &arr );
  for ( size_t r = 0; r < get_rows(); r++ )
    for ( size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++ )
      printf( "arr[%zu][%zu] = %.2f\n", r, c, arr[r][c] );

  free( arr );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: presumably this means that it is unnecessary to pass the value `cols` to the function?

Comment: It *is* necessary to specify `cols`, hence why it's the first parameter to the function.

Comment: Thanks, I see that now. Impressive, I didn't know that you could use the value of a previous argument in the function signature like that.

Comment: Mainly because `cols` must be declared before it can be used in the array pointer declaration.  **Edit** Per H&S, you could also use `[*]` to specify a variable length array dimension, but the version of gcc I'm using doesn't yet support that.

Comment: I like this ,but It seems that does not  to compile with clang 3.1. (gcc is no problem)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Interesting; I compiled this with -std=c99 -pedantic, so it shouldn't be relying on any gcc-isms.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: In the `allocate` function, I must explicitly dereference `arr` before indexing it; remember `arr` is a pointer *to a pointer* to an array.

Comment: Since C99 think that we should allow this, but I think if there is a bug in clang.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
void allocate(double *((*grid)[]), size_t cols)   
                      //    ^grid is pointer to array of `double *` type
```

to

```
void allocate(double (**grid)[], size_t cols)  
                      //   ^grid is a pointer to pointer to array of `double` type
```

Comment: euuuuhhh... nope. This is completely wrong. This will not allow OP (or anyone else, for that matter) to allocate an array more than one dimension, at least not correctly.

Comment: @user3477950 there was a typo in my original code but now I've fixed it, this seems to work fine. What do you suggest is the problem?

Comment: @user3477950; Could you explain why this is wrong? Do you know where to use *pointer to pointer* ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY No, I'm not. Haccks is confusing pointers and arrays.

Comment: @user3477950 Compile modify the source then say it again.

Comment: @TomFenech; No. In case of `double (*array)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof *array);` `sizeof *array` is correct. You could replace it with `sizeof **grid`.

Comment: @TomFenech; I think you are comparing my answer with John Bode's answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot what I put in the original question...I think that we both agree with one another now anyway. Although I'm not sure that `sizeof **grid` will work correctly unless you specify the number of columns in the function signature, as per John's answer.

Comment: _sizeof **array will be calculated at compile time._ What about the story?

Comment: Is the `array` Tom's `array`? to talk of `sizeof **array` instead of `sizeof *array` It is abrupt.

Comment: Size of the VLA will be calculated at runtime even in the case of John's.

Comment: also `sizeof(**grid)` It is not possible to calculate the size of the incomplete type(E.g `double (**grid)[]`) .

Comment: @BLUEPIXY; Oh!! Forgot about that :P

Answer (score 2):

You definitely **can** return a pointer-to-multidimensional-VLA. I'm not sure if one can declare a function with such a return type, but hey, why not just return `void *` instead?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *allocate(size_t n, size_t k)
{
    int (*p)[n] = malloc(k * sizeof *p);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            p[i][j] = i * j;
        }
    }

    return p;
}


int main(void)
{
    size_t n = 3, k = 5;
    int (*p)[n] = allocate(n, k);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", p[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why one should want to return pointer from a function if there is an option to do the same without returning it ?

Comment: @haccks Because why not? For me, an allocator function conceptually **should** return the allocated pointer. I hate APIs where a pointer-to-pointer is dereferenced and filled in with a pointer to newly allocated memory. This is like asking "why is malloc declared as `void *(size_t)` instead of `void(void **, size_t)`?"

Comment: @user3477950 DANGER! You are returning a pointer to memory alloc'ed in stack. Your pointer will be dangling just after returning; and all the memory `malloc`ed (and their pointers stored there) will be leaking.

Comment: @rslemos Nope. Where would I?

Comment: @user3477950 oh, nevermind. I saw `*p[n]` instead of `(*p)[n]`.

Comment: But somehow I miss some memory allocation. For a n x k matrix I would expect either `malloc(n * k)` or n `mallocs` of k elements.

Comment: @rslemos `malloc(k * sizeof *p)` allocates one contiguous block of memory for `n * k` elements, since `p` is a pointer to array of `n` elements, hence `*p` is an array of `n` elements.

Comment: @user3477950, oh yes, sorry. I'll stop coding for today. Shame on me. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocate a **contiguous** two-dimensional array (as C does with static 2D arrays), your `malloc` will look like

```
element_type *array = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof *array);
```

To access the array you'll have to do pointer arithmetic yourself:

```
*(array + i*cols + j);
```

The code you describe is more akin to [jagged arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

Comment: I'm aware of this approach but I would much rather use the variable length array based approach as shown in the question, so that I can use two indices in the code rather than computing one. The first block of code in my question does *not* produce a jagged array, it produces a block of contiguous memory.

Comment: Jagged arrays are composed of `rows + 1` blocks of contiguous memory. One block for the lines, and then `rows` blocks for each line.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
static void
xalloc(int rows, int cols, double (**array)[cols])
{
  *array = malloc(rows * sizeof(**array)) ;

  double* p = (void*)*array ;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < (rows * cols) ; ++i)
    p[i] = i ;
} ;

int
main()
{
  int rows = 10 ;
  int cols =  7 ;

  double (*array)[cols] ;
  xalloc(rows, cols, &array) ;

  for (int r = 0 ; r < rows ; ++r)
    {
      printf("%3d:", r) ;
      for (int c = 0 ; c < cols ; ++c)
        printf("%3d:%4.0f", c, array[r][c]) ;
      printf("\n") ;
    } ;
} ;
```

Which I think is consistent with the desire to use a Variably Modified type for the array.

Mind you, I also think it's horrible... but hey, it's not every day one gets to write something quite so abstruse as `double (*array)[cols]` and get away with it.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your code like below.

```
void allocate (double ((**grid) []), size_t cols) {
    size_t rows = 5;
    double (*arr)[] = (double (*)[]) malloc (rows * sizeof (size_t));
    *grid = arr;
}

int main () {
    size_t cols = 5;
    double (*grid)[] = 0;
    allocate (&grid, cols);
    printf ("%x", (void *)grid); // to show that the memory is being allocated
    return 0;
}
```